# VLookup a value in workbook with code in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have two workbooks: one with the macro and one with data. I am trying to look up a value in the workbook with data. After the code with `VLookup` is reached it stops, and everything after isn't executed.

I checked all things I can think of. I checked if some random cell from data workbook can be reached: `MsgBox (budgetWorkbook.Sheets("sheet 1").Range("E16").Value)`, it works fine.

I checked if my search value equals with the corresponding value in column A of data workbook, it works - it msgboxes "Equals".

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim budgetItemSheetName As String
i = 1
Dim budgetItemValue As Long
MsgBox (budgetWorkbook.Sheets("sheet 1").Range("E16").Value) 'shows up
If budgetItemNames(i) = budgetWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1".Range("A16").Value) Then
    MsgBox("Equals")  'shows up
End If

budgetItemValue = Application.VLookup(budgetItemNames(i), _
  budgetWorkbook.Sheets("sheet 1").Range("A:B"), _
  2, False)  'fails, but it should find the search value in A16 cell and give B16 cell's value

resultArray(i) = budgetItemValue  'doesn't work
MsgBox (budgetItemValue)   'doesn't show up
```

**EDIT**: Looks like I will have to use a custom search function.

Comment: You have checked that `budgetItems(i)` is in the lookup range, but have you checked whether `budgetItemNames(i)` is in the lookup range?  (P.S.  If you aren't using `Option Explicit` in all your code modules, learn to do so - you won't regret it.)

Comment: how does it fail? does it throw an error? does it work when you manually enter the formula?

Comment: VLookup is picky about datatypes, whereas the equality operator in VBA is very forgiving. For example if one cell is formatted as a string and the other as in integer VLookup won't find the value, even if they are textually the same.

Comment: @YowE3K, Sorry, it was just a mistake of retyping it from excel. I have only`budgetItemNames(i)` and that's what I was checking.

Comment: @RealCheeseLord It doesn't execute code following the line with the function and get `#VALUE!` in a cell I typed my custom function with that code snippet in.

Comment: OK - tip for next time - copy/paste your code into the question.  It avoids people wasting time looking at things that are just typos and then they can concentrate on more esoteric issues.  (I think Achim Gmeiner will be on the right track - it will be a difference in data types that VLookup won't handle but VBA does.)

Comment: @Achim Gmeiner I pass to `VLookup` a `String`. The `A16` cell is in `General` format. I tried changing that to `Text`, it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Ans You could try using INDEX and MATCH function. https://www.deskbright.com/excel/using-index-match/

Answer (score 1):

Just made a small test with a small lookup table, Column A and Column B and the lookup value in Cell D1:

```
Public Sub TestVLookup()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim rng As Range

Set wb = Application.ThisWorkbook
Set sht = Application.Sheets("Tabelle1")

budgetItemValue = Application.VLookup(Cells.Range("D1"), sht.Range("A1:B5"), 2, False)
Debug.Print "The Result is " & budgetItemValue

End Sub
```